# Custom application property to be supplied to spring boot app through cmd line

Tags: spring-boot

I was wondering if we can supply a custom attribute (a key to be in application.properties file), I know for sure that -Dserver.port=8080 works, and overrides the property value, but server.port is a spring boot's expected property value. 
How about something other than that, for example a jdbc connection string or service name? does -Ddb.service.name=dbservice work?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, any property can be set via system property. You can use `-D` or `--` notation. There are also a variety of property sources Spring Boot uses:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html